# Can you tap a card whenever you want?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a colorless 1/1 untapped creature that has no abilities, can I just tap this card whenever I want? Or let's say I have a artifact/enchantment/planeswalker with no abilities. Can I just tap it?

Comment: If you have something to add to your question, just edit it into the actual question text. There is no reason to repeat information in a comment.

Comment: Are you looking for a quick off-the-cuff answer, or a deep rules-lawyering answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

nope

2 relevant rules:

> 110.5c A permanent retains its status until a spell, ability, or turn-based action changes it, even if that status is not relevant to it.

and

> 110.5. A permanent’s status is its physical state. There are four status categories, each of which has two possible values: tapped/untapped, flipped/unflipped, face up/face down, and phased in/phased out. Each permanent always has one of these values for each of these categories.

it retains its status until something changes it, and tappedness is part of that.

a sort-of meta-guessing "here's how I would design a game" answer, while we're at it: There's no way they would have printed [Gilder Bairn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152046) or [Immovable Rod](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=531912) without closing that loophole.

Comment: The entire idea of untapping as a cost (rather than an effect) is questionable if you could just tap a card whenever you want. There is a functional difference in that an effect goes on the stack and a cost doesn't, but it's still questionable.